# Error in simple haskell program with generic data type

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, interpreter

I'm writing a generic interpreter in Haskell but I have a problem with the definition of the environment.

```
data Variable a = Variable {
     name :: String,
     vtype :: String,
     value :: a -- Rather than value :: Int
}
```

After the definition of the Variable structure, I need to define the status of the program (environment) that is simply a List of Variable. If I write

```
type Env = [Variable]
```

I had the following problem:

> generic_interpreter.hs:11:13: error:
> * Expecting one more argument to `Variable' Expected a type, but` Variable' has kind `* -> *' * In the type` [Variable]'
> In the type declaration for `Env'
> 11 | type Env = [Variable]

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `type Env a = [Variable a]`

Comment: Not works, the new problems are: 
- Variable not in scope: main :: IO a0 
- Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)

Comment: as the error says, that is because your program lacks a `main`, this has nothing to do with the `Env`. It is simply *another* problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Variable` type has a type parameter `a`, so you can not use `[Variable]`, since the list needs a concrete type.

You thus can define a type `Env a` that then is a list of `Variable`s of type `a`:

```
type Env a = [Variable a]
```